# Can you add a payment ID to a subaddress during an exchange withdrawal?

Tags: payment-id, exchange, sub-address

Can one add a payment id to a subaddress? When withdrawing from an exchange you can put in a payment id and a subaddress. Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

A payment ID is part of a transaction, not an address. Therefore, yes, if the exchange supports adding a payment ID field, it will be added to the transaction and you can view the payment ID in your wallet incoming transfers.

Comment: so yes you can combine a payment id with a subaddress?

Comment: As per answer, a payment id is part of the transaction. So yes, if the exchange offers payment id support.

Comment: @Patoshiパトシjtgrassie is talking about the old style unencrypted payment ids, and not the new style integrated address encrypted payment ids. There is no such thing as an integrated subaddress.

Comment: so don't put a payment id with a subaddress your saying? it wont work?

Comment: Not quite. It depends on the exchange. If it allows you to use a payment id (as a separate field) it should be fine. There are 2 ways of using payment ID's. 1) as a separate field and 2) included in an integrated address (that is an address with embedded payment ID).